# Adding a version to time-series data

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I wish to store time series data with versioning.  By versioning, I mean that I might have a metric `energy_mwh` with tag `meter_id=123` and a fieldset something like this `time=2016-01-01 10:00, mwh=20.50, read-time=2016-01-01 20:15` and if I re-read the meter at a later time I want to keep both the new and old version of the meter reading.  Later when I query the data I will be mostly just interested in the `mwh` value with the highest `read-time` for any given `time`.   If I query over a range of times the `read-time` is going to vary.

I am thinking of using InfluxDB or some other time series database with a similar data model.

Is there a right way of doing this?   I believe that I must keep `read-time` as a tag - not a field or I will lose the older version of the data.   I guess that is answer - but it doesn't feel right to me to have what I see as a piece of data: `read-time` sitting in an identifier - specifically a tag.   Am I on the right track?

Comment: You can also read/write/report with versioning in Axibase Time Series Database as described here: https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/data-model/versioning/

Comment: Thank you @SergeiRodionov.   I will be looking further into axibase.